# Combining two antenna at a right angle to get a better signal?

Tags: arduino, antenna

I got two of these: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01KH3VEGS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01KH3VEGS)
But I only need one at the moment so I thought I could combine the two antenna to get a better signal in this manner (90 degrees to each other):
[image: Diagram]

So I have two questions.
Will combining the two antenna in this way actually help the signal or will it mess with it?
Both wires from the antenna are black so I don't know the polarity of the signals, how can I check that so the signals actually combine properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work particularly well.

The combined antenna will act similarly to a single antenna at 45 ° orientation. If you flip the wires on one, the 45 ° angle will rotate 90 °.

Imagine that only one antenna receives a signal -- i.e. aligned with the transmitter. The other antenna won't receive anything, and so the signal from the 1st antenna will split between the receiver and the 2nd antenna (which in fact will re-radiate it). Thus, in this case, your receiver will see LESS signal.

Similarly, if the transmitter is aligned at 45 °, then both antennas will receive 1/sqrt(2) of the signal strength, and ultimately when combined, you will eventually get the same signal strength as a single antenna.

This general issue occurs because the antenna signals are vectors, and you can't (easily) combine these vectors. Ideally, you would use separate receivers for each antenna and select the one with the best signal.

For higher frequency signals where the antenna could be a wire, the general way to solve the orientation issue is to use circular polarization. If the Tx has linear polarization (e.g. a simple antenna), and the receiver has circular polarization (can be made with 2 simple antennas physically and electrically 90 ° rotated), then you will receive a 50 % strength signal AT ALL orientations.

Combining this way can't easily be done with ferrite rod antennas.

Note that attempting this won't damage your receiver.

You can check the polarity of the wires by placing both antennas parallel to each other (but spaced a distance apart (as allowed by the wires)), and by reversing the wiring, you will find that one polarity DOES receive a signal, while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [readable version of the datasheet/documentation](https://www.universal-solder.ca/downloads/60khz.pdf) that is shown only as a poor-quality image on the Amazon link.

**The short answer is no, combining antennas will not improve reception.** Instead it would have the detrimental effect of altering the specifications of a single antenna, because you will essentially be connecting two inductors in parallel, halving the inductance and changing the value the circuit was designed for.

Consulting the documentation, it has some advice for improving reception:

> The ferrite antenna should also be pointing orthogonally relative to the transmitter.
> [image: Antenna orientation]

> The ferrite bar antenna should be located as far as possible from conductive metal walls, PCB ground plane or ferromagnetic objects (speakers).

There is an entire section on improving signal reception which I will quote here in case the link dies:

> **Getting a signal**
> The antenna is sensitive for magnetic and electric disturbances. As an example, in digital radio controlled clocks it is known that LCD displays, refreshed using a 32Hz signal, has a1875th odd harmonic hitting exactly at 60kHz and its amplitude can be strong enough (µVrms level) to reduce the sensitivity. The antenna and module
> placement is critical and one should maximize distance to other disturbing electronics and metal/ferrous parts which might affect the antenna and the reception.
>
> A good place to start is to put the module close to a window and turn the antenna to an optimal position relative the transmitter (see the figure 2 above). As the second step trigger the fast startup by moving PDN control from power down (PDN=VDD) to power up (PDN=VSS) which will make the AGC find its level within a few seconds if
> the receiving conditions are sufficient. Initially the OUT signal should be high but soon after finding a signal (or disturbance in case of poor SNR) the output goes low and after a few seconds it should start receiving pulses. If the output stays low all the time there is probably some disturbance stronger than the signal. If the signal is bad, change location and repeat the fast startup by setting PDN=VDD (power down) to PDN=VSS (power up).
>
> Please note that if PDN control is not used but the P1 pin (PDN) is permanently tied to GND (receiver on), the start-up time before the receiver finds the signal can take a few minutes.

Comment: 1875th odd harmonic?! Wow.

Comment: 60kHz / 1875 = 32 Hz, so I see how they got that number, but I'm skeptical it's technically accurate because harmonics typically attenuate as you go up the series. But I'll leave that for someone with a higher pay grade to explain. :)

Answer (score 0):

These antennas are directional, with signal nulls along the ferrite axis. So pointing one axis toward Fort Collins doesn't yield much signal.
[image: two antennas in series] If you *must* use two antennas, a series connection is likely better. As you've pointed out, wire ends look similar, so phasing two in series requires aiding rather than opposing.

The only reason you see two antennas at right-angles is for users who don't know their directions relative to Fort Collins.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common way to mount these two antennas in the way you describe in the RC world. For example a RC plane when flying horizontally would best receive/transmit signal with the same polarization as the RC control unit, when the airplane turns at 90 degrees, it has to have a 2nd antenna with polarization 90 deg off.

Now it is not clear if you have a fixed transmitter/receiver setup or mobile. In case of fixed, it won't give any benefit.

Comment: Yeah, the reasoning behind the 90 degree offset is that I don't know the orientation that the device will be pointed in and I want it to work without as much fiddling

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the dual-antenna setup common in RC applications is designed with antenna diversity in mind - meaning that the antennas are individually routed into the receiver and impedance matched, etc. It's not the same as just connecting two antennas electrically together.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a diversity receiver, like a Wifi MiMo access point, it would help for when either endpoints orientation is not matched by giving you 2 polarizations.

However, if you just put 2 antennas on one port, the damage you do by mismatching the port, and also the potentially destructive interference would in all likelihood degrade performance.

There is a way to do this that works if you want to operate on both sides of a very thick wall that does work, but you need a good RF splitter that keeps the impedances equal to what they normally would be. Each antenna sees a 3.x dB loss, but if the wall is 10dB there is net improvement.